# React Native how to array filter by 2 conditions?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, filter

I have function as below to filter my array from list:-

```
      .map(d => ({ ...d, data: d.data.filter(c => c.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()))}))
      .filter(d => d.data.length);
      setFilteredData(filtered);
```

It's working fine when filter by name. But how can I add in another element to filter?

I tried add in this code **c => c.element.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()))** but does not work

```
      .map(d => ({ ...d, data: d.data.filter(c => c.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase(),c => c.element.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()))}))
      .filter(d => d.data.length);
      setFilteredData(filtered);
```

Any idea? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can use and operator (&&) to connect 2 condiftions. `d.data.filter(c => c.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()) && c.element.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()))`

Comment: hi @kiuQ, thx for your prompt reply. I tried but no luck. After apply even search name also does not work.

Comment: You would like to filter the data with both `name` and `element` key contain the same search text or one of them is fine?

Comment: I have a search box (searchText), then i would like to search name / element by using this seachText

Comment: If only one of them need to contain search text, please use or operator ( || ). `d.data.filter(c => c.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()) || c.element.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()))`

Comment: Great! it's work.. pls reply me in answer so i can tick for it.. thx for your help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR operator ( || ) to connect the conditions together. It will filter the data if one of the condition is fufilled.

```
d.data.filter(c => c.name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()) || c.element.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase()))
```